# creating dynamic text fields with id for each

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to create id for each text field  but not able to achieve that. This is the code I have which does not help me to create id for each text field. I have tried many different approaches but they didn't help.

Below is my Code:

```
 <v-text-field class="font-weight-bold" v-for="(value,key) in requests" :label="key" :value="value" :key="'req-param-'+key" :id="value.ID" readonly></v-text-field>
```

Comment: `value.ID` is undefined no ? I would try something like : `id="'id + key"`

Comment: can u plz add a pen for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-text-field
      class="font-weight-bold"
      v-for="(value, key) in requests"
      :label="key.toString()"
      :value="value"
      :key="'req-param-' + key"
      :id="`id-${key}`"
      readonly
    ></v-text-field>
    <v-btn @click="showLog">click here and see the console.log</v-btn>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: () => ({
    requests: ['row 1', 'row 2'],
  }),
  methods: {
    showLog() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.requests.length; i++) {
        console.log(document.getElementById(`id-${i}`));
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```